# Programmatically get markdown files from external repositories and convert them to pages

Tags: docpad

Hey I know I can use the docpad-plugin-downloader plugin to grab markdown files from external repositories.

However, I am unsure how I can conver these grabbed md files so that they can render as a page in docpad.

What I am trying to do is setup a documentation site using docpad and it is working great. However I would love it if docpad could grab my readme files from my external repositories and convert them to actual pages, so I would only have to update my readme files to update my documentation site.

Was wondering if you had any ideas? :)

Comment: If your downloading markdown files into your documents folder then I would assume that the docpad watcher would detect the new files and generate the corresponding page. Is this what you are meaning?